# ffmpeg 32 bit crashed on x64 Windows for av01 format

Tags: ffmpeg, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I have tried to use ffmpeg to convert av01 videos to H264 on x64 Windows, and the ffmpeg 64bit worked very well. However when I try to use ffmpeg 32bit exe to convert av01 to H264 or any other video format on Win7/Win10 x64, the ffmpeg crashed immediately and the window throws "ffmpeg has stopped working".

My command line:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i av01.mkv av01.mp4
```

If I test this with ffmpeg 32 bit and Windows 7 32 bit, it could work.
And, I can convert all other formats to H264 on Win7/Win10 x64 with ffmpeg 32 bit, except av01 format.

ffmpeg 32 bit version: ffmpeg-20181215-011c911-win32-static

So, it seems ffmpeg 32bit could only not work on 64 bit Windows for av01 format. Is it a bug or the av01 decoder's issue?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Do you mean `AV1`- if so, which decoder? There's two external decoders and no native ones.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks for your comment. To be honest i don't know... I used the ffmpeg static exe binary to try..

Comment: It shows "libaom-av1" as decoder

Comment: @Gyan and I could only find libaom-av1 as AV1's decoder in FFMPEG

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution:

I changed the command from

```
ffmpeg.exe -i d.mkv d.mp4
```

to

```
ffmpeg.exe -threads 1 -i d.mkv d.mp4
```

Now it works!